# Using the Creation spell to smash foes with a heavy block of metal

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The spell *Creation* (PHB, p. 229) states:

> You can also use this spell to create mineral objects such as stone, crystal, or **metal**. The object created must be no larger than a 5-foot cube, and the object must be of a form and material that you have seen before.
>
> The duration depends on the object’s material. [...]
>
> **Precious metals — 1 hour**

Gold (which could be clearly counted as a "precious metal") has a density of 19.32 g/cm³. A five-foot cube of gold weighs roughly 62 tons.

Note that the spell does not limit whether the material has to be created on the floor or in the air. It doesn't declare any specific physic rules, either, so we can - and have to - assume that the physics apply as if it were normal materials of their respective kind.

If someone were to drop a 62-ton 5-foot-cube on top of you, you would be *obliterated*. Using a 9th-level spell slot, you could even create a 25-foot cube, if you so desired.

**Are there any rules that would indicate how to rule / handle a situation like this?**

**How can I balance this spell if it can create an object that will instantly kill most creatures below it?**

Comment: [Source for how fast you fall](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/75954/how-far-do-you-fall-per-turn)

Comment: The range on Creation is 30ft, so presumably you could only create the block of metal 30ft straight up and at lower heights the farther away it is from you. You could, however, be flying to then bombard creatures on the ground with this spell.

Comment: the form is a cube, the size doesn't matter, the form is still the cube. Either way, you could also choose a block of stone and still crush the target to death.

Comment: We mark questions as duplicates based on the question not the answers. The question is the same. Since whatever method you use for damage is homebrewed, the answer to "how to balance?" Is dependent on that.

Comment: I don't agree that this is a duplicate. The OP appears to be asking for mechanical solutions to his problem that aren't just "do a bunch of damage".

Comment: Right now the question reads as an exact duplicate of the other question to me. If this is a question about balance and not calculating the damage from a falling object, then you may want to edit your question to make that clearer.

Comment: @Szega good point. In fact, that more or less solves the problem - if you've got 10 rounds to kill something that's not defending itself in the meantime, you'll probably manage to kill it without this spell ^^

Comment: @PixelMaster do you intend to edit the question or is it just being left as a duplicate?

Comment: yes, I'll leave it like this (though I added a paragraph at the end). Its 1-minute casting time renders balancing obsolete, and therefore also my question.

Comment: I have edited your question so that it might be considered not a duplicate. We do not allow you to write answers in your question body.